# Two-Finger Scrolling in LXDE (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: 12.10, lxde, scrolling

I can't get two-finger scrolling to work in LXDE w/ Ubuntu 12.10.

Here's a brief history. I upgraded my machine (an old [Dell Inspiron 1200](https://www.google.com/search?q=dell%20inspiron%201200&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=v5_fUM_GDIWQ2AX2jIH4BA&biw=1024&bih=682&sei=wZ_fULOQHbCl2AX_wYDYBw)) from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 12.10 all in one fell swoop, and then installed LXDE and completely removed all `ubuntu-desktop` packages using [the psychocats instructions](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelubuntu) (because I greatly dislike Unity). In short, it's more or less basically like Lubuntu now, as far as I can tell. All other programs and settings work just fine -- but not two-finger scrolling.

Help?

(Oh, and there will be bonus points for anyone with right ideas about how to enable "natural scrolling" after I get the two-finger scrolling working!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=119#p306) and have summarized it below.

**TWO-FINGER SCROLLING**

Create and/or edit a file called `mouse.fdi` like so:

`sudo leafpad /etc/hal/fdi/policy/mouse.fdi`

Paste in this stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
 <device>
  <match key="input.x11_driver" string="synaptics">
   <merge key="input.x11_options.VertEdgeScroll" type="string">true</merge>
   <merge key="input.x11_options.HorizEdgeScroll" type="string">true</merge>
   <merge key="input.x11_options.MaxTapTime" type="string">0</merge>
  </match>
 </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

Save! Reboot! Done!

**BONUS: "NATURAL SCROLLING"**

Enable "natural scrolling" (AKA "reverse scrolling") by creating a file in the home directory called `.Xmodmap` like so:

`leafpad ~/.Xmodmap`

And paste in this stuff:

`pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`

Save! Reboot! Done!

**DOUBLE BONUS: DISABLE TAP-TO-CLICK**

Open the session `autostart` file:

`sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

And append this stuff (or simply run it from the command line for a one-off solution):

`synclient MaxTapTime=0`

Save! Reboot! Done!

Answer (score 0):

Two finger scrolling only works on computers that support it. Yours might not. My Dell Latitude D830 doesn't support two finger scrolling, so I use edge scrolling.

Comment: Good point, but it worked fine on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and then again when I upgraded to 12.10. It only STOPPED working when I followed the psychocats instructions and made my system a "pure" Lubuntu. It's quite possible that I removed a package necessary for two-finger scrolling, but I have no way of knowing which package that might be. Or it could be that Lubuntu doesn't support two-finger scrolling. I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the excellent @jrc03c answer, you can also use `synclient` to achieve the natural scrolling:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-30  # Trackpad: natural scrolling
synclient MaxTapTime=0         # Trackpad: disable tap-to-click
```

Worked for me in my old MacBook white 2007 with Lubuntu 16.10.