# Touchpad - Two fingers scrolling

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, toshiba-satellite, scrolling

I have some problem to configure my touchpad,
I have a toshiba satellite z30a1gt and ubuntu 14.04.
On the settings -> mouse and touchpad i don't have a tab for touchpad.
i have download all the software that written here on the forum and nothing changed.

```
xinput; uname -r:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`cat /etc/default/grub | grep CMDLINE`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

`uname -r`

```
3.16.0-45-generic
```

When i run "`Synaptic`" it says "`No touchpad was found in this system`...."

Please, how can I fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Amir

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: Possible doplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/234236/two-finger-scrolling-in-lxde-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Where is output of `uname -r` and also please add `cat /etc/default/grub | grep CMDLINE`

Comment: @ZviadGabroshvili It is not related and not a duplicate.

Comment: And also please specify what was "download all the software that written here on the forum".

Comment: i created the mouse.fdi file, reboot and no changes.

Comment: Synaptiks, Gpointing, tried Synaptics.

Comment: Attempt #3: Please add the output of `uname -r` to your question. That was the last one.

Comment: uname -r added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check if the touchpad is enabled in bios, then check if it is not blocked by some <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> or some other Fx key with a touchpad icon on it.

If that does not help, you can upgrade Linux kernel. Probably your touchpad is not properly detected. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

Comment: "upgrade Linux kernel" fixed the problem, thank a lot guys !!!